# Can't bundle rubyracer on rails to get twitter bootstrap working RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to get twitter bootstrap to work for days, but I can't seem to bundle the rubyracer with the new rails. This is my gemfile for the twitter bootstrap.

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why "can't you seem" to bundle it?  Do you get errors?  What are they?  Is "the new rails" 4.1?

Comment: This is my error
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: And what happens when you `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing `node.js` as an alternative (http://nodejs.org); I've found it to be a better platform all-around, with less deployment surprises.

Evidently `therubyracer` uses quite a lot of memory, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#therubyracer